How to change the tag <H1> and <H2> instead of <section> and <subsection> in the tagged pdf output (changing custom tag name instead of default)
Based on the new version of tagpdf.sty, tag structure of section, list are automatically tagged, but I need to  change the below tag names

<H1> and <H2> instead of <section> and <subsection>

for List need to change <L> instead of <list>

how to change the tag name <p> instead of <text-unit><text>


Could anyone guide me how to change custom tag name instead of default.
Note: I am using TeXlive 2024 and lualatex-dev.exe for compiling the document
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,title,table},%pdfversion=1.7,pdfstandard=ua-2,
uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Sample title}

\maketitle

\section{A Head}

Sample text

\subsection{A Head}

Sample text11111111111111\footnote{222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222} 333333333333333333333333

\subsubsection{A Head}

Sample text

\section{Another A Head}

Sample text

\begin{enumerate}
\item Fitst list item 
\item second list item 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item Fitst list item 
\item second list item 
\end{itemize}


\tagpdfsetup{table-header-rows=1}
\begin{table}[!b]
\caption{Table Head}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
THead 1 & THead2 & THead3\\
\hline
1 & 2 &3\\
4&5&6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{bib01} bibligraphy item 1
\bibitem{bib02} bibligraphy item 2
\bibitem{bib03} bibligraphy item 3
\bibitem{bib04} bibligraphy item 4
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}



I think you should explain why: we have worked hard on the PDF 2.0 structures and roll-mapping for PDF 1.7 fallback

@JosephWright: I am  not used pdfversion=1.7, i just commented that in the MWE

I think you want to use the highest PDF version possible here - but my question still stands anyway as I'm interested in the wider use case

(Side remark: ua-2 should be used together with pdfversion=2.0)
There is currently no easy way to adjust single tag names (but this will change).
You can only adapt all tag names. There you have two options:

At first you can tell acrobat to apply rolemapping:



Then acrobat will show you the standard tags:

The LaTeX names will still be there, but not visible in the interface.

If you really want to get rid of the LaTeX tag names completly, you can use

\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}

This can be done in the preamble, but also somewhere in the document. It will then affect the following tags. E.g. here I put it before a subsection:

